# splitCsv join channel for each row multiple times nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have a csv file `my_csv.csv` with three columns, I can read it using `spliCsv` which looks like:

```
csv_ch.splitCsv(header:false,sep:',').map{row->tuple(row[0],row[1],row[2])}.view()
[chr1, 0, 1 10]
[chr1, 1, 10 20]
[chr1, 2, 20 30]
[chr2, 0, 1 10]
[chr2, 1, 10 20]
[chr2, 2, 20 30]
[chr3, 0, 1 10]
[chr3, 1, 10 20]
[chr3, 2, 20 30]
...
```

I have another channel `map_ch` which looks like

```
map_ch.view()
[chr1,[map1.txt]
chr2,[map2.txt]
chr3,[mp3.txt]
chr4,[mp4.txt]]
```

....

Now, I want to get:

```
[chr1, 0, 1 10,[map1.txt]
[chr1, 1, 10 20,[map1.txt]
[chr1, 2, 20 30,[map1.txt]]
[chr2, 0, 1 10,[map2.txt]
[chr2, 1, 10 20,[map2.txt]
[chr2, 2, 20 30,[map2.txt]]
[chr3, 0, 1 10,[map3.txt]]
[chr3, 1, 10 20,[map3.txt]
[chr3, 2, 20 30,[map3.txt]]
```

If I use `join` operator, I am getting only

```
[chr1, 0, 1 10,[map1.txt]
[chr2, 0, 1 10,[map2.txt]
[chr3, 0, 1 10,[map3.txt]]
```

This is not what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combine operator does the magic.

map_ch.combine(csv_ch,by:0)

It gives me exactly what I need.